# I have a program that randomly selects a string from an array. After the second attempt, the result stays the same. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, arrays

This is in C#.

My program randomly picks a string from the array and then asks if the choice is acceptable. If they select yes, they can end the program. If they select no, it re-selects and asks if the choice is acceptable again.

The problem, is that after selecting no and it repeats, it'll show the same result each time.

The Code -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {

        public string[] randString;
        public Random rand = new Random();
        public bool customerSatisfied;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();


            p.PostString();

            //Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void PostString()
        {




              randString = new string[]
            {
            "Apple",
            "Orange",
            "Banana",
            "Pear",
            "Grape",
            "Cherry",
            };


            int randStringIndex = rand.Next(randString.Length);
            string selectedString = randString[randStringIndex];

            while (customerSatisfied == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Selecting a Random Fruit");

                Console.WriteLine("The Pick is " + selectedString);

                Console.WriteLine("Is this acceptable?");

                string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

                if (userInput == "yes")
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("The Program is finished. Press any Key to Close ");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    customerSatisfied = true;
                }
                else if (userInput == "no")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Making Another Attempt ");
                    Console.WriteLine("The Pick is " + selectedString);
                    Console.WriteLine("Is this acceptable?");

                    Console.ReadLine();
                }




            }

        }

    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You set `string selectedString = randString[randStringIndex];` once. So of course it will be the same. Everything you want repeated needs to go in the loop. Also I would get rid of your `else if` because the while loop does the extra tries for you (and this else if would duplicate the same message again if you don't change it)

Comment: Put that random number generator inside while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is obvious, put the next lines inside the while loop:

```
int randStringIndex = rand.Next(randString.Length);
string selectedString = randString[randStringIndex];
```

Otherwise the selected string will be always the same.